# Lucas sequence are elliptic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divisibility, elliptic-curves, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

I'm studying Elliptic Curves and EDS (Elliptic divisibility sequences) and working on Silvermans exercises 3.34 in "The arithmetic of elliptic curves":

"An EDS over $K$ is a Sequence $(W_n)_{n\geq 1}$ defined by four initial conditions $W_1, W_2, W_3, W_4 \in K$ ans satisfying the recurrence:

$W_{m+n}W_{m-n}W_1^2=W_{m+1}W_{m-1}W_n^2-W_{n+1}W_{n-1}W_m^2$

I already proved that the even terms of the Fibonacci-sequence satisfy this recurrence.

The next exercise is to generalize this result and find a subsequence of the sequence $(L_n)_{n\geq 1}$:

$L_1=1 \quad L_2=P \qquad \qquad \qquad L_{n+2}= PL_{n+1} - L_n$

which also saitsfies the recurrence above.

I already recognized the the given formula describes a Lucas-sequence :
$L_n= \frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b} $ with $P=a+b, Q=ab=1$

I just need an idea to proof that such a sequence satisfies the recurrence relation above.

Comment: $L_n = \alpha^n+ \beta^n$ for some $\alpha,\beta$

Comment: Please clarify, are you seeking a closed form expreseion for $L_n$?

Comment: No, I already have the closed form $L_n=\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$ with $P=a+b, Q=ab$ . Just need an Idea to proof that such Lucas-sequence with $Q=1$ staisfies the elliptic recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Given the definitions of [Lucas sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence)

$$ U_n := (a^n-b^n)/(a-b), \quad V_n := a^n+b^n, \quad Q := a b\tag1 $$

and

$$ T :=  U_{m+n}U_{m-n}U_k{}^2 - U_{m+k}U_{m-k}U_n{}^2
 + U_{n+k}U_{n-k}U_m{}^2 ,\tag2 $$

verify using elementary algebra that

$$ T = U_{m+n}U_{m-n}U_k{}^2(Q^k-Q^n)/Q^k. \tag3 $$

Now specialize to $\,W = U,\, Q = k = 1\,$ to get the desired result.